# Does every sequence of group epimorphisms (between finitely generated groups) contain a stable subsequence?

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, geometric-group-theory

I have a question that is related to the topic of limit groups:

Let $G$ and $H$ be finitely generated groups and let $(\varphi_n: G \to H)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of group epimorphisms. Does there exist a stable subsequence of  $(\varphi_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$?

This is the definition of "stable sequence":

Let $G$ be a group and $(\varphi_n) _{n \in \mathbb{N}}⊂ \mathrm{Hom}(G, H)$. The sequence  $(\varphi_n) _{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is stable if
for any $g ∈ G$ either $\varphi_n(g) = 1$ for almost all $n$ or $\varphi_n(g)\neq 1$ for almost all $n$.

I conjecture that the answer to the question is positive, because the statement of the question is used on page 27 of the following article (in the article we have a sequence of epimorphisms $g_n: F_l \to L$ to which the statement of my question is applied to):

https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.10278.pdf

**Edit: In the above article we have the situation that G is a free group of rank at least two and H is a non-abelian limit group. So it would be sufficient if somebody can answer my question for this situation. Of course you can still say something to the general situation.**

Edit: "Almost all" means that the statement ist true for all natural numbers with possibly a finite number of exceptions.

Comment: No. Of course the sequence you gave is not stable. But the question is if one can always find a **subs**sequence that is stable. And here we can find one. The subsequence that contains only the projections onto the first factor ist stable. Also the subsequence that contains the projections to the second factor is stable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. This is just (metrizable) compactness in the space of normal subgroups of $G$. It is enough to assume that $G$ is countable (finitely generated plays no role).

Namely, let $N(G)\subset 2^G$ be the set of normal subgroups. It is closed in the compact space $2^G$, hence is compact.

Let $M_n$ be the kernel of $\varphi_n:G\to H$. Then there is a converging subsequence $M_{i(n)}\to M$. Then for $g\notin M$ (resp. $g\in M$), for each $n$ large enough (bound depending on $g$) we have $\phi_{i(n)}(g)\neq 1$ (resp. $\phi_{i(n)}(g)=1$).